# Laravel 5.3 Password Grant Tokens [user credentials incorrect]

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

Setup Laravel's 5.3 Passport using vagrant/homestead. Following along until i reach [Password Grant Tokens](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#password-grant-tokens)

Here I found this GuzzleHttp snippet to make post to `/oath/token`:

```
    Route::get('/api_grant', function(){
    $http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

    $response = $http->post('http://mavrik-cms.io/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => '6',
            'client_secret' => 'BBlhjUlGsbde5zQ3LBHAr6inJoQVFOMIZlR1RFUI',
            'username' => 'mrricki.m.usmc@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'secret',
            'scope' => '',
        ],
    ]);

    return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
});
```

Although i have sent all of the required and correct information I continue to receive: (Note: Im the only user so its my email and dummy password and the client is correctly associated to my user_id on the oauth clients table and password_client is set to 1);

```
{"error":"invalid_credentials","message":"The user credentials were incorrect."}
```

[image]

Ive been messing around with this for a few hours now. I have tried all possible combinations of user and password.(email from user model as username, user from user model as username, password in user model as password, etc..).

Comment: I ran into the same issue and it ends up that i had forgotten to bcrypt the password when creating the user

Comment: For me it was the solution to provide the correct username. Of course it was not the "name" but the "email", which is set to be unique in my eloquent model.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem and it ended up happening because I use a `username` field in my table for authentication instead of the default `email`.

To accommodate that behavior, I had to override `findForPassport()` in my `User` eloquent model. `UserRepository` from `passport` defaults to `email`

```
if (method_exists($model, 'findForPassport')) {
    $user = (new $model)->findForPassport($username);
} else {
    $user = (new $model)->where('email', $username)->first();
}
```

Not sure if this helps, but this worked for me.

```
public static function findForPassport($username)
{
    return User::where('username', $username)->first();
}
```

Comment: i added this method in my User model and still get "{"error":"invalid_credentials","message":"The user credentials were incorrect."}
" i'm sending a post request with postman and 100% sure my credentials are correct

Answer (score 1):

I also was facing the same problem but I got it solved by bcrypting the password of user in table
You can bcrypt password online here http://bcrypthashgenerator.apphb.com/ and then save the password in table against the specific user

Also you must pass emailid ( value of column 'email' in table) in username key  in post data

Comment: Same issue here w/ Laravel 5.5. My legacy database was using MD5, whereas Laravel uses bcrypt with 10 passes by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `Hash::make('your_password')` or `bcrypt('your_password')`, bests! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I change there file

1. app\Http\Kernel.php change 'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class to this

   `'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class`
2. add this function to user class or add in Client modal.

   `public static function findForPassport( YOUR PARAMERT )
   {
       return User::where('mobile', YOUR PARAMERT)->first();
   }`
3. my Client.php

`use Notifiable,HasApiTokens;`

`protected $fillable = [
       'name', 'mobile', 'email', 'avatar','password','active','enterprise_id'
    ];`

`public $timestamps = true;`

```
Protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public static function findForPassport($mobile)
{
    return User::where('mobile', $mobile)->first();
}
```

3. to get user info after sent token i use this code

   `$request->user('api');`
4. test your api in api.php file in route like that

   `Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
       return $request->user('api');
   });`

if user login you get information of user